# Pandas df.describe() returning wrong result

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I tried getting into Kaggle with house sales competition.
I spent some time getting rid of columns that according to what I got from `df.describe()` seemed useless (all zeros).

Why does `df.describe()` return a result that is not true?

[image]

Comment: pandas, python version? does it also happen right after you only load the dataset?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this seemingly weird behaviour is that I used `pd.options.display.chop_threshold = 100` without knowing what it does.
From the pandas docs:
"If set to a float value, all float values smaller than the given threshold will be displayed as exactly 0 by repr and friends. [default: None] [currently: None]"

After removing that line, the `describe()` function returns the result as expected.